# Deleted data in table view will come back

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a chat application with groups. I need to make it so the users can delete groups. I made everything and it worked except for one thing. If the user delete a group and than create a group with another name. The user will see the deleted group name and not the new group name. Once the user clicks on the group, the name will be updated to the new group name. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Group Delete Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = familyTableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FamilyTableViewCell
    let familyName = cell.familyName.text!

    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let usersReference = ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("Familys").child(familyName)

    usersReference.removeValue { (removeError, ref) in

        if(removeError != nil){
            print(removeError as Any)
            return
        }
    }

    let familyNamesReference = ref.child("Family Names").child(familyName)

    familyNamesReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let familyUid = dictionary["UID"] as! String

            let familysReference = ref.child("Familys").child(familyUid).child("Users").child(uid)

            familysReference.removeValue(completionBlock: { (removeError, ref) in

                if(removeError != nil){
                    print(removeError as Any)
                    return
                }
            })
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)

    self.familys.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.savedNames.removeAll()
    self.savedFunctions.removeAll()
    self.savedImages.removeAll()
    self.namesOtherWay.removeAll()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.familyTableview.setEditing(false, animated: true)
        self.familyTableview.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        self.familyTableview.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Create Cell Code:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return familys.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = familyTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "familyCell") as! FamilyTableViewCell

    if(savedNames[indexPath.row] != nil && savedFunctions[indexPath.row] != nil && savedImages[indexPath.row] != nil){
        cell.familyName.text = savedNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.familyFunction.text = savedFunctions[indexPath.row]
        cell.familyImage.image = savedImages[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        let family = self.familys[indexPath.row]

        cell.familyName.text = family.name
        self.savedNames.updateValue(family.name!, forKey: indexPath.row)
        self.namesOtherWay.updateValue(indexPath.row, forKey: family.name!)
        cell.familyFunction.text = family.function
        self.savedFunctions.updateValue(family.function!, forKey: indexPath.row)

        let imageLink = family.imageLink

        let url = URL(string: imageLink!)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            if(error != nil){
                print(error as Any)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    let image = downloadedImage

                    cell.familyImage.image = image
                    self.savedImages.updateValue(image, forKey: indexPath.row)

                    self.familyTableview.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    return cell
}
```

I hope someone will be able to help me! Thanks.

Comment: add cellforRowAtindexpath method .

Comment: @KKRocks, what do you mean?

Comment: in question nothing any cellforRowAtIndexpath method . mean tableview's datasource method.

Comment: @KKRocks, I'm sorry I forgot to add that in my question. I've updated my question with my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Are you using FireBase? Seems to me this is a FireBase question, not a table view question. You need to put details on the database you're using in your question, and probably add a keyword as well.

Comment: Are you sure this is a firebase problem? Because everything works fine except for displaying the right name. The names are correct in the variables but they just won't display right. I really don't know why this is.

Comment: what happens when the user click on the group?

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs , a new viewcontroller will open with all the messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying things out for hours I finally found a solution! I just had to clear the textfields and uiimages when I removed the group (cell).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i am totally wrong but should this part

```
self.familys.remove(at: indexPath.row)
self.savedNames.removeAll()
self.savedFunctions.removeAll()
self.savedImages.removeAll()
self.namesOtherWay.removeAll()

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.familyTableview.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    self.familyTableview.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    self.familyTableview.reloadData()
}
```

not inside this part?

```
familysReference.removeValue(completionBlock: { (removeError, ref) in

            if(removeError != nil){
                print(removeError as Any)
                return
            }
            // add the part here
        })
```

because it can be, that you reload the table before the observer recognize that the data was removed.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I've just tried it but still didn't fixed the problem.